# What is the Alternative for Form Tag in React Fluent-UI?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, office-js, office-addins, fluentui-react

I am currently developing Microsoft Addin with react. I have added `TextField` to the AddIn.
But I couldn't get the value from inputs because there is no `Form` tag in fluent-ui.

What can I do to resolve this?

This is the component.

```
<Stack>
  <TextField placeholder="User Name" />
  <TextField placeholder="Password" type="password" />
  <PrimaryButton className="ms-welcome__action" iconProps={{ iconName: "ChevronRight" }}>
    Sign In
  </PrimaryButton>
</Stack>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way to solve you're problem, but you can add a value to each TextField that is linked to a prop in your component, like that :

```
<Stack>
  <TextField placeholder="User Name" value={userName} onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)} />
  <TextField placeholder="Password" type="password" value={passWord} onChange={(e) => setPassWord(e.target.value)} />
  <PrimaryButton className="ms-welcome__action" iconProps={{ iconName: "ChevronRight" }}>
    Sign In
  </PrimaryButton>
</Stack>
```

The onChange handler reset the prop the user is modifying.
Don't forget to declare `userName` and `passWord` via the `useState` hook :

```
const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
const [passWord, setPassWord] = useState("");
```